# Material with refraction index similar to Si

Tags: materials

I am looking for a material with a refractive index over the visible spectrum , which is close to the refractive index of Si, but which does not oxydise in air.

Do you know of any such material ?

Thank you.

**Edit:**
Some more information. A optical reflector should be build from Si. I will not go into the detail, since it is irrelevant to the question, but I will provide all necessary information. The list is ordered according to importance:

1. The complex refractive index should be close to Si over the entire visible spectrum
2. The material should not oxydize in air
3. The working conditions should be between -30°C to 60°C.
4. Not necessary, but it would be great if epitaxy on single-crystal silicon is possible.

Comment: $\ce{Si}$ is not transparent and thus can't have refractive index. Did you mean something about *reflection*? And $\ce{Si}$ doesn't oxidise in air either.

Comment: @Gert Every material has a (complex) refractive index, transparent or not, and Si is very reactive against air and immediately forms an oxide layer on the surface.

Comment: Si might passivate?

Comment: Silicon is one of very few elements (3) with a self-limiting oxide layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the range of the [visible spectrum, ~1.8 - 3.1 eV, or 700-400 nm](https://www.asu.edu/courses/phs208/patternsbb/PiN/rdg/color/color.shtml), the [refractive index (*n<sub>D</sub>*) of Si varies from about 3.5 - 5](http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/Si/optic.html), though it is also absorbent and somewhat reflective over that range. [Gallium(III) phosphide, $\ce{GaP}$ is one material that comes close to that.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_refractive_indices) It should be fairly stable in air at STP.

Of course, it all depends on your intended use. At what wavelength should *n<sub>D</sub>* match that of Si? At what temperature and in what atmosphere will the material be? Does the crystal structure of the material need to match that of Si, so that a regular layer can be deposited? More information is needed for the answer to be of any use.

Comment: thank you very much  for the answer ! This is very informative ! I will add more information to the description of the question.

Comment: Do you know if epitaxy on single-crystal silicon is possible ?

Comment: According to http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5617118/ it is feasible despite 0.37% lattice mismatch between Si and GaP. Not much of a gap...